# I found an error in software implementation in the paper currently under peer review

Tags: research-process, peer-review, conference, paper-submission, computer-science

I found an error in software implementation in the paper currently under peer review.

Modifying the software does not change the idea of the paper and does not change the major conclusion and discussion. But all the values in the result will be changed, so I have to change all the figures.

If I receive a request for a revision (If they do not reject), I plan to inform this problem to the editor.

In this case, how will the future process generally proceed?

I wonder whether all the submission processes should be restarted from the beginning or fixed in the revision stage.

Comment: It sounds like you have already decided what to do.  What is the question?

Comment: When I inform the editor of my mistake, I wonder about how the editors usually handle it.

That link is helpful to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably inform the editor that you have found errors that don't (dramatically?) affect the results and can clean them up in a future revision. Don't withdraw the paper, I suggest.

Let the editor decide what is sensible to do. They may be fine to let the process continue. But if reviewers flag the error it might be worse in the end.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
When the result comes out, I will inform my mistake to the editor and wait for the decision.